# show editable field when empty

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have this problem: I have a component with which I create editable fields.
If the field is already populated, everything works fine. I see the database value, I can click on it and change it.
If, on the other hand, in the database that value is empty, it is "hidden" in the view. In this way it is not possible to click on it to insert a value in the editable field.

I tried to get around the obstacle by inserting a: placeholder = "placeholder" but I don't even see that.

How can I do?

This is my visualization file:

```
        <div class="py-0 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-10 sm:gap-4 my-2">
            <dt class="text-md leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900 sm:col-span-2 self-center">
                {{ $trans('labels.description') }}
            </dt>
        </div>
        <div class="py-1 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-10 sm:gap-4">
            <dd class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-600 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-10 self-center">
                <v-input-text-editable
                    v-model="task.description"
                    @input="updateTask()"
                    :placeholder = "placeholder"
                />
            </dd>
        </div>
```

---

```
props: {
    users: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },

    description: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    }
},
```

---

```
data() {
    return {
        task: new Form({
            description: this.description
        })
    }
},
```

this is my component:

```
<template>
    <div class="block w-full">
        <div v-if="!editable" class="cursor-pointer" @click="enableEditMode()">
            {{ valueAfterEdit }}
        </div>

        <div v-else class="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm" v-click-outside="handleClickOutside">
            <div class="relative flex-grow focus-within:z-10">
                <input @keyup.enter="commitChanges()" class="form-input block w-full rounded-none rounded-l-md transition ease-in-out duration-150 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" v-model="valueAfterEdit" ref="input"/>
            </div>

            <span class="btn-group">
                <button @click="discardChanges()" type="button" class="btn btn-white rounded-l-none border-l-0">
                    <svg class="h-4 w-4 text-gray-400" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path d="M10 8.586L2.929 1.515 1.515 2.929 8.586 10l-7.071 7.071 1.414 1.414L10 11.414l7.071 7.071 1.414-1.414L11.414 10l7.071-7.071-1.414-1.414L10 8.586z"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>

                <button @click="commitChanges()" type="button" class="btn btn-white">
                    <svg class="h-4 w-4 text-gray-400" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path d="M0 11l2-2 5 5L18 3l2 2L7 18z"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            value: {
                type: String,
                default: null
            },

            allowEmpty: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                editable: false,
                valueBeforeEdit: this.value,
                valueAfterEdit: this.value
            }
        },

        watch: {
            value(val) {
                this.valueBeforeEdit = val;
            }
        },

        methods: {
            handleClickOutside() {
                this.disableEditMode();
                this.commitChanges();
            },

            enableEditMode() {
                this.editable = true;
                this.$emit('edit-enabled');

                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    this.$refs.input.focus();
                });
            },

            disableEditMode() {
                this.editable = false;
                this.$emit('edit-disabled');
            },

            commitChanges() {
                if (!this.allowEmpty && this.valueAfterEdit !== '.') {
                    this.$emit('input', this.valueAfterEdit);
                    this.disableEditMode();
                }
            },

            discardChanges() {
                this.valueAfterEdit = this.valueBeforeEdit;
                this.disableEditMode();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: kindly request you to improve the question. mention the way how you fetch the data and how you set it up to a text file. so we can identify where the issue occurs. up voting this question to improve knowledge with world wide community

Comment: @MohamedRaza hi, I added my component to the question. perhaps it can be useful in finding a solution.
I need that when the editable field is empty it must still be visible to be able to click on it and insert the text.
At this moment, however, if it is empty it is hidden in the view and I cannot click on it to insert the content.

Comment: Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I can not see the fetching function on your question about where do you fetch those data. please update it on the question